# Problems on metric spaces and similar request

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm taking a course on real analysis which includes metric and normed spaces, continuous and uniform continuous functions, compact and connected sets...

I have done several problems but I think I need more practice. Where could I find problems related to these topics (undergraduate level)? (if they are solved it would be nice)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MIT courseware has a course on metric spaces [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-s097-introduction-to-metric-spaces-iap-2022/).